# WSO2 API Manager deployment with scalable traffic manager jndi configuration contains "/test" for QueueConnectionFactory in the documentation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm referring the "Scalable Traffic Manager Deployment Patterns for WSO2 API Manager - Part 1" article and it contains the following configuration for the **jndi.properties** file

```
connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5673'
connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/test?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5673'
```

What is this `/test` url does and should it need to be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here actually what we need to add is the first line. Second line was there in default jndi.properties file. So you can safely ignore second line as you will need to add only first line to existing file.

Thanks,
sanjeewa.